# tkinter does NOT update boolean - but does update a TABLE of booleans

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I cannot get tkinter to update a pair of simple "application global" boolean variables to match that of the associated checkbox.  The booleans are initialized, updated and stored in one file and are referenced (read-only) by another file.  Regardless of the checkbox state the booleans never change from their default value.  (A side point of note: The initial values of False/True get changed into 0/1, presumably due to the problematic way tkinter impelements booleans).
Curiously, there are NO problems with the similar “application global” TABLE of booleans that corresponds to a table of tkinter checkboxes.  The table is an instance of a class defined by a third file. The table resides in the same file (and is treated in the same way) as the simple booleans.
All boolean values are used (read-only) in one file (File1.py) and are only modified by the other file (File2.py).  Explicitly returning the problem booleans (from File2.py to File1.py) did not work.

The environment being used is Windows 7, Python 3.2.2 on Eclipse Juno (4.2.2, build M20130204-1200) with the Pydev 2.7.32013031601 plug-in.  The application is being run from the Eclipse console.

By the LEGB scoping rules everything seems OK (the include and global statements are present and the dotted name form is being used for the externally defined “application level” global variables). As I see it, either all boolean updates should work or none should work.  So why does the boolean table work properly but not the simple booleans - and what is needed to get the simple booleans to work properly?
Speculating, could it have something to do with the way python implements variables that have basic values (e.g. 0, 1, 2, 3, True? False?) as “shared values” instead of separate variables - and this leads to problems when referencing these simple values from other modules?

The sample application consists of 3 files; each has been reduced as far as possible while remaining able to show the problem.   When run on Windows 7 you should see this:[image: Tkinter window sowing rusluts of running sample code]

File1.py - mainline, contains the callback function “Get_User_Selections”:

```
from tkinter  import *
from tkinter  import ttk
import File2 
#==========================================================================
def Get_User_Selections( ):

    print( "\nDoAllReports=", File2.DoAllReports, "DoNoReports=", File2.DoNoReports )

    if ( not File2.DoNoReports ) :  
        for row in range( len( File2.ChosenReports ) ):
            for column in range( len( File2.ChosenReports[ 0 ] ) ) :              
                if ( File2.ChosenReports[ row ][ column ].get() or
                     File2.DoAllReports ) :

                    print( "Do report  (", row, ',', column, ')' )               
    return
#==========================================================================         
def CreateTheReports( *args ):
    Get_User_Selections( )
    return
#==========================================================================
''' *********** MAIN PROCEDURE ***************** '''
root = Tk()
root.title( 'tkinter Boolean problem' )

mainframe = ttk.Frame( root )
mainframe.grid( )

File2.ChooseReports( mainframe )

DoItButton  = Button( mainframe, text = 'DO IT!', command = CreateTheReports )
DoItButton.grid()

root.mainloop()      
#==========================================================================
```

File2.py - defines the GUI, updates all of the “application level global” booleans:

```
from tkinter  import *

# import the custom "GUI table" widgit class (which works as expected)

from TkinterCheckBoxTableClass import TkinterCheckBoxTableClass

# Determine the table "shape" (in the original application the strings become  
# the row and column headers, these headers NOT shown by this example code).

RowTitles    = [ "A", "B" ] 
ColumnTitles = [ "1", "2", "3", "4" ]

DefaultReports = [ ]
for i in RowTitles :
    for j in ColumnTitles :
        DefaultReports = DefaultReports + [ False ] 

# Initialize the three "APPLICATION LEVEL" global variables that preserve the
# user choices across invocations of the routine.  Each invocation is caused
# by the user pressing the "DO IT!" button on the GUI.

ChosenReports = DefaultReports     # table of user choices (works properly)

# These two "application" globals override the table (above) of individual 
# choices.  "DoNoReports" overrides "DoAllReports"; both override the table. 

DoAllReports  = False    # does not work, value never changes    
DoNoReports   = False    # does not work, value never changes    

#==========================================================================
def ChooseReports( ParentFrame ):    
    # Purpose : Interface between the "application globals" and what appears
    #           on the GUI.  Called from File1.py whenever user presses 
    #           the "DO IT" button

    global ChosenReports   # "application" global, resides in this file
    global DoAllReports    # "application" global, resides in this file
    global DoNoReports     # "application" global, resides in this file

    GuiTable = [ [ IntVar() for j in range( len( ColumnTitles ) ) ]
                                        for i in range( len( RowTitles ) ) ]

    ThisFrame = LabelFrame( ParentFrame, text = " Select Reports " )    
    ThisFrame.grid( row = 1, column = 0 )

    DoAll  = IntVar( value = DoAllReports )
    DoNone = IntVar( value = DoNoReports )

    SelectAll = Checkbutton( ThisFrame, variable = DoAll, text = "All",
                             onvalue = True, offvalue = False)
    SelectAll.grid( row = 0, column = 1 )

    SelectNone = Checkbutton( ThisFrame, variable = DoNone, text ='None',
                              onvalue = True, offvalue = False )
    SelectNone.grid( row = 0, column = 2 )

    TableFrame = LabelFrame( ThisFrame, background = 'grey', 
                             borderwidth = 1, relief = FLAT )
    TableFrame.grid( row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 3, rowspan = 2 )

    # Create the custom Checkbox Table, works without any problems.

    ChooseTheReports =  TkinterCheckBoxTableClass( FrameID = TableFrame,
                                              UserSelections = GuiTable )
    # Update the "application level" globals
    DoAllReports  = DoAll.get( )
    DoNoReports   = DoNone.get( )
    ChosenReports = ChooseTheReports.getTable( )
    # Passing back the above variables in the return statement did NOT work.
    # Returning them shouldn't even be needed since a) they have "application" 
    # level scope, b) they reside in THIS file and c) are ONLY modified by THIS 
    # file (with the new values being accessible from other files).   
    return  

#==========================================================================
```

TkinterCheckBoxTableClass.py - implements the table of booleans:

```
'''
Implements a 2-D matrix (table) of tkinter checkboxes (for Python 3.x).
'''
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class TkinterCheckBoxTableClass( object ):   
    '''
    Python 3.x interface to a matrix (2-D table) of tkinter checkboxes.
    Must pass a tkinter frame and the matrix to the constructor.
    Class constructor parameters:    
        FrameID             - tkinter parent frame that displays the table
        UserSelections      - matrix of True/False values passed to/from to GUI         
    Entire Table Methods:    
        getTable()         - extracts 2-D array of UserSelections from tkinter
    '''
    '''----------------------------------------------------------------------'''
    '''
    Constructor
    '''   
    def __init__( self , FrameID, UserSelections ) :               
        self.frameID             = FrameID      
        self.userSelections      = UserSelections       
        self.rowCount            = max( 1, len( self.userSelections ) )
        self.columnCount         = max( 1, len( self.userSelections[ 0 ] ) )                              
        self.checkBoxTable  = [ [ IntVar() for j in range( self.columnCount ) ]
                                           for i in range( self.rowCount ) ]
        # Construct and display the table of tkinter checkboxes
        for i in range( self.rowCount ) :
            for j in range( self.columnCount ) :
                self.checkBoxTable[i][j] = Checkbutton( self.frameID,
                                    variable = self.userSelections[ i ][ j ],
                                    onvalue  = True, offvalue = False )
                self.checkBoxTable[i][j].grid( row =  i + 1, column =  j + 1, 
                                               sticky = W )
    '''----------------------------------------------------------------------'''
    '''Methods:'''    
    def getTable( self ) :
        for i in range( self.rowCount ) :
            for j in range( self.columnCount ) :
                self.checkBoxTable[i][j] = Checkbutton( self.frameID,
                                     variable = self.userSelections[ i ][ j ],
                                     onvalue  = True,offvalue = False )
                self.checkBoxTable[i][j].grid( row = i + 1, column = j + 1,
                                               sticky = W )
        return self.userSelections   
''' END CLASS '''
```

BTW, as to PEP8: see the section immediately after the PEP8 introduction. ;>)  I am also well aware of the advantages/disadvantages of “application globals” and of the kludgey “create a universal include file and import it everywhere” approach; one that I’d prefer NOT to use unless there is ABSOLUTELY no other simple way of fixing my problem. (I much prefer importing modules ONLY where they are needed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define `DoAllReports` and `DoNoReports` like this:

```
DoAllReports = IntVar(False)
```

Then in your client code, use `DoAllReports.get()` instead of just `DoAllReports`, same for `DoNoReports`.  Don't create the separate `IntVars` `DoAll` and `DoNone`; they are not necessary, just use `DoAllReports` and `DoNoReports`.

The reason these lines don't do anything:

```
DoAllReports  = DoAll.get()
DoNoReports   = DoNone.get()
```

... is that they are executed *during the construction of your dialog* before the user has had a chance to click on the buttons they're attached to. So you're just getting back the same values with which you just initialized the `IntVars`. You don't update your global variables at any other time, such as when the user clicks `DO IT!`, so naturally they are never updated.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer.  There is a gotcha! though: You can't put the line "DoAllReports = IntVar(False)" in the global namespace (error message implies tkinter has not been set up when python hits that line during startup).  The fix is to leave the global declaration alone (to force variable into global namespace) then coerce it's type to IntVar by adding this weird looking line at start of File2.ChooseReports: "DoAllReports=IntVar(value=DoAllReports)".  After .get() was appended to the variable references in File1.Get_User_Selections everything works.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you only set the value of these global variables when you create the gui. I see no code that changes their value once the gui appears and the user is allowed to interact with the checkbuttons. Just because you initialize them with the result of `DoAll.get()` doesn't mean they continue to get updated when the checkbuttons are checked.

Why do you need these variables? You already create `IntVar`s that *do* update when the user clicks on a checkbutton, why add another level of abstraction? Just use `DoAll.get()` whenever you need the value.

The reason the table works is because it is a table of `IntVar`s, which are constantly updated when the checkbutton values change.

Comment: The abstraction is exactly the point - it's interfacing (isolating the value from how it was is obtained).  Immediately converting tkinter values into standard types (e.g. from IntVar to int), localizes the conversion and also eliminates the need for inserting .get() in EVERY other routine that uses the value (e.g. the "if" tests in Get_User_Selections). Assume that routine is preexisting code that you cannot change.  For that routine to use the GUI value you need to pass the value back a python boolean, not a tkinter "booleanVar".

Comment: @user1459519: I think maybe you misunderstand how event-based programming works. That `IntVar` will change whenever the user clicks on the related checkbutton. Unless you add code to copy the value to your global variable, that global variable will become out of date. You must either create code to update your variable every time the value changes, or fetch the value only when you need it. Personally I think the latter is cleaner and easier to maintain.

Comment: I also think you might not understand the real value of calling `get()` everywhere it is used: it instantly tells you that the value is tied to a widget, which aids in maintenance. Using global variables, it becomes harder to answer the question "where did the value of this variable come from?". But, of course, ultimately you need to use what you are most comfortable with. I just wanted to make sure you understood the ramifications of having a global variable that you have to keep synchronized with another object, which is precisely what the `IntVar` is designed to do.

Comment: I accidentally hit some weird key combination and my comments were prematurely posted.  What got omitted was my thanks for your help, especially the mystery of why the table worked.  Also, due to the combination of your comments with those of @kindall I've gotten it to work - but not quite in the way I'd prefer. I eventually want to eliminate all ".get()"s from Get_User_Selections - but doing also affects my class so it's something for another day.  Any hints?

Comment: Premature posting happened again ! Had to totally remove the comment , it's the UP arrow that's doing it.  WIll try again

Comment: The "application" globals were intended to be updated every time anything changes on the GUI.  To do this I'm now thinking I should use the "command=" option on my tkinter widgits, probably with lambdas.  BTW I NEVER use the “create a universal include file and import it everywhere” for cross-module globals.  The way I do it requires dotted notation and thus documents where the entity resides.  Important since the sample code services only one of several subframes.  Also all "application" globals are put into the same file as the frame definition to ensure all have the same dotted prefix.

Comment: My reasoning for wanting to complete isolate tkinter (e.g. no "get()"s in Get_User_Selection) from application logic comes down to risk management - what do you have to change when you have to switch GUIs?  On a big project this is not a trivial consideration, especially when there are legal/safety/contractual/certification implications